# Como terminar un patron en regex con un posible caracter en Python

Tags: python, regex

Me preguntaba si hay alguna forma de crear un patrón que pueda encontrar una cadena de texto entre "google.com/" y "?" Incluso si "?" no está en la cadena de texto base:

```py
import re

url = "www.google.com/search?q=whatever
re.search(r"google.com/(.*)\?", url).group(1)

url = "www.google.com/search
re.search(r"google.com/(.*)\?", url).group(1)
```

Esta es la salida

```
>>> search
>>> Error: Your regular expression does not match the subject string.
```

Comment: python o javascript? Las etiquetas están para usar las correctas, no son pokemon que debas coleccionar.

Comment: Gracias por el aviso, se me había pasado, ¿en cualquier caso sabrías responder mi pregunta? @Benito-B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El patrón es simplemente cualquier cosa que no sea "?": `r"google.com/([^?]*)"`.

#### Demo

```
import re

patron = re.compile(r"google.com/([^?]*)")

tests = [
"www.google.com/search?q=whatever",
"www.google.com/search",
"www.google.com/searching?q=whatever?",
]

for url in tests:
    print(url, patron.search(url).group(1))
```

produce:

```
www.google.com/search?q=whatever search
www.google.com/search search
www.google.com/searching?q=whatever? searching

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Eso se puede lograr sin usar expresiones regulares, usando lo que ya ofrece Python.

###### Código

```
tests = [
"www.google.com/search?q=whatever",
"www.google.com/search",
"www.google.com/searching?q=whatever?",
]   

for cadena in tests:
    # busco la subcadena "google.com/", obtenemos donde empieza dicha subcadena
    # y le sumamos el largo de esa misma subcadena para obtener donde termina.
    pos_final_google_punto_com = cadena.find("google.com/") + len("google.com/")

    # quitamos de la nueva cadena todo lo anterior al final de la cadena "google.com/"
    nueva_cadena = cadena[pos_final_google_punto_com:]

    # en la cadena resultante, buscamos el signo de pregunta. Si no lo encuentra, devolverá -1
    pos_signo_pregunta = nueva_cadena.find("?")

    # Si lo encontró...
    if(pos_signo_pregunta != -1):
        # quitamos el signo de pregunta y todo lo que le sigue.
        nueva_cadena = nueva_cadena[:pos_signo_pregunta]

    print(cadena, nueva_cadena)
```

###### Produce

```
www.google.com/search?q=whatever search
www.google.com/search search
www.google.com/searching?q=whatever? searching
```